# Angular 2 CSRF Token for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, csrf

I'm currently trying to create a small web app with Angular 2 as my front end and Rails 4 as my backend - my backend is just an API while my front-end is just sending out requests.

I ran into CSRF token authenticity errors today when trying to submit a post request - how do I add these CSRF headers into my Angular 2 headers?

Comment: What code did produce the error, what's the exact error message?

Comment: There's a PR for it: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8898

Answer (score 0):

For this use [angular_rails_csrf](https://github.com/jsanders/angular_rails_csrf) gem

Comment: I think this gem was originally designed for AngularJS 1.0

Comment: @bhanu Angular version is OK, both 1 and 2 are using `X-XSRF-TOKEN` token in header. But that gem only support which rails version below 5.

Comment: I am not use with rails 5